# write bash code loop a file line by line that have values, first word as a row and create csv

Tags: shell, awk, perl, array, read

i have this sample data

```
dn; uid=456456456,cn=users,dc=efsfb,dc=org,dc=co;
objectclass; top;
objectclass; person;
objectclass; organizationalPerson;
objectclass; inetOrgPerson;
uid; 456456456;
givenName; MONICA;
employeeType; CC;
telephoneNumber;456456456;
telexNumber;958;
postalAddress;19770726;
initials; ARBOLEDA;
title; F;
cn; MONICA ARBOLEDA RAIGOSA;
mail; fghfghfgh@gmail.com;
sn; RAIGOSA;
userPassword;;
ibm-entryuuid;;
;;
dn; uid=456456,cn=users,dc=efsfb,dc=org,dc=co;
objectclass; top;
objectclass; person;
objectclass; organizationalPerson;
objectclass; inetOrgPerson;
uid; 456456456;
givenName; SONIA ESPERANZA;
employeeType; CC;
telephoneNumber;456456;
telexNumber;958;
postalAddress;456456;
initials; CASTRO;
employeeNumber;51932787;
title; F;
cn; SONIA ESPERANZA CASTRO TORRES;
mail; fghfh@gmail.com;
sn; TORRES;
userPassword;;
ibm-entryuuid;;
;;
dn; uid=456456,cn=users,dc=efsfb,dc=org,dc=co;
objectclass; top;
objectclass; person;
objectclass; organizationalPerson;
objectclass; inetOrgPerson;
uid; 456456;
userpassword;;
sn; OLIVERA;
givenName; MAURICIO;
cn; MAURICIO REINALES OLIVERA;
employeeType; CC;
mail; mfghfh@gmail.com;
telephoneNumber;57383;
telexNumber;958;
postalAddress;19800101;
initials; REINALES;
employeeNumber;456456;
title; M;
ibm-entryuuid;;
;;
dn; uid=CC39681904,cn=users,dc=efsfb,dc=org,dc=co;
objectclass; top;
objectclass; person;
objectclass; organizationalPerson;
objectclass; inetOrgPerson;
uid; CC39681904;
givenName; MARIA DEL PILAR;
employeeType; CC;
telephoneNumber;217001;
telexNumber;958;
postalAddress;456456;
initials; ACUNA;
employeeNumber;456456;
title; F;
cn; MARIA DEL PILAR ACUNA PENA;
mail; mafsdfsf@gmail.com;
sn; PENA;
userPassword;;
ibm-entryuuid;;
;;
```

if you see, is not repeat, some can have data others no, but the common is the first word before of delimiter ";" is a row

how can i convert all before data to csv like this sample

```
uid       employeeType            name                  email
mafsdfsf    cc                      maur                  mafsdf 
mafsdfsf   CC5dfgdfg8               monica               modfgfdg@g
blabla       blabla                 blabla              blabla
```

i have read with awk, with read IFS, readarray, but i cannot make this deal

thanks for anyone can help me

but in this case with all fields

Comment: Can you, please, make the expected result consistent with the sample data ? For instance, I can see no uid with value "mafsdfsf". And as for the emails "user@example.com", do you want the "@example.com" part or not ?

Comment: Your new data does not match your requested output.  `uid` never contains anything like `mafsdfsf` or `blabla`.  It contains mostly numbers.  and employeType only ever seems to contain  `CC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using perl.  There's probably a perl module to parse LDAP data, but I didn't bother looking for one, this was easy enough to do without any modules.

BTW, you seem to want TAB separated values, not COMMA separated.  I've named the script accordingly.  If you want actual CSV then it's easy enough to modify (but remember to double-quote each field - the `dn` field in particular already contains commas - or just use the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) module to generate correct CSV output).

```perl
$ cat ldap2tsv.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @keys = qw(dn uid mail);                 # array of keys we're interested in
my $match = '^(' . join("|",@keys) . ');';  # turn @keys array into a regex
$match = qr($match);                        # pre-compile regex for performance

my %data = ();                              # hash to hold values for each key

print join("\t", @keys), "\n";              # print header line

while(<<>>) {
  next unless m/$match/;
  my ($key,$val) = split /\s*;\s*/;
  $data{$key} = $val;

} continue {
  if (m/^;;$/ || eof) {
    print join("\t", @data{@keys}), "\n";
    %data = ();
  };
};
```

This first creates an array containing the key names we're interested in, then build and pre-compiles a regex to match them from the array, and prints the keys in a header line.  `$match` ends up containing the regex `^(dn|uid|mail);`

Then it iterates over each line of the input, ignoring lines that don't match one of the keys.  If the current line matches, it is split on `;` characters (with optional leading and/or trailing spaces, `\s*`) into scalar variables `$key` and `$val`.  These are use to insert the data from the current line into the `%data` hash.

The `continue` block is executed after each line - I'm using it here to check if a line contains only `;;` or we're at the end of file.  If so, then print out the current data line AND clear the current values in %data.

Sample output:

```
$ chmod +x ./ldap2tsv.pl
$ ./ldap2tsv.pl data.txt 
dn      uid     mail
uid=remisor1,cn=users,dc=efsfb,dc=org,dc=co     remisor1
uid=paciente1,cn=users,dc=efsfb,dc=org,dc=co    paciente1
uid=CC522496sdad48,cn=users,dc=efsfb,dc=org,dc=co       CC5dfgdfg8      modfgfdg@gmail.com
```

---

If you want the output in nicely aligned columns, you can pipe it into `column -t`.  Note, however, that this will convert the TAB characters to two or more spaces.

```
$ ./ldap2csv.pl data.txt | column -t
dn                                                 uid         mail
uid=remisor1,cn=users,dc=efsfb,dc=org,dc=co        remisor1    
uid=paciente1,cn=users,dc=efsfb,dc=org,dc=co       paciente1   
uid=CC522496sdad48,cn=users,dc=efsfb,dc=org,dc=co  CC5dfgdfg8  modfgfdg@gmail.com
```

---

After changing the `my @keys = qw(dn uid mail);` line to `my @keys = qw(uid employeeType givenName mail);` and running it against your new data set, the output now looks like this:

```
$ ./ldap2csv.pl data2.txt 
uid     employeeType    givenName       mail
456456456       CC      MONICA  fghfghfgh@gmail.com
456456456       CC      SONIA ESPERANZA fghfh@gmail.com
456456  CC      MAURICIO        mfghfh@gmail.com
CC39681904      CC      MARIA DEL PILAR mafsdfsf@gmail.com
```

or nicely formatted for human readability with `column -s $'\t' -t`:

```
$ ./ldap2csv.pl data2.txt | column -s $'\t' -t
uid         employeeType  givenName        mail
456456456   CC            MONICA           fghfghfgh@gmail.com
456456456   CC            SONIA ESPERANZA  fghfh@gmail.com
456456      CC            MAURICIO         mfghfh@gmail.com
CC39681904  CC            MARIA DEL PILAR  mafsdfsf@gmail.com
```

**Note:** there is no `name` key in your data.  There is a `givenName` key.  I've used that instead.  Same with `email` - there is no `email` key, but there is a `mail` key.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i see with large data, print the last line, no all the data, will make a edit

Comment: this should work with input data of any size.  Does your data come from a windows box with CR+LF line-endings instead of unix-style LF line-endings?  If so, convert with `fromdos` or similar first.

Comment: ok i make edit, but the data is a txt, separate by  ;; i dont know where the data comes, only a txt that i can process

Comment: yes, I know that the data is text separated by `;;`.  That's why I wrote the script to process exactly that.   to find out what kind of text file it is, run `file filename`.   e.g. I ran `file` on `data.txt` and it printed `data.txt: ASCII text`

Comment: how can i convert this in csv?

Comment: with your new output requirements, change the `my @keys = ...` line to `my @keys = qw(uid employeeType name mail);` so that it extracts the keys you now want instead of the keys you initially said you wanted.   Nothing else in the script needs to change.    I wrote it this way deliberately to make it easy to add or change the fields to be extracted.

Comment: yes thanks i change this lines for make a new data

Comment: sorry for disturb you, is my first time with perl

Comment: thank you a lot ./test1.pl test.txt > userformatter.csv